# sum if weekday is equal to the weekday excel

Tags: excel, if-statement, syntax

I would like to solve some syntax error due to lack of skills. I would like to bind this weekday check with one formula.

This is wrong and I need to sum up the `(W11/X11*Y11*1.25)` part and showing the day of transaction is only on weekday and not weekend on Z11. Meaning to say I need to bind this formula together and then sum for the rest blanketed columns on Cell Z11.
`=((T11/X11)*Y11)+((U11/X11)*Y11*1.25)+((V11/X11)*Y11*1.5)` with `=IF(AND(WEEKDAY(A11)>=2, WEEKDAY(A11)<=6), (W11/X11*Y11*1.25))`

Thank You In Advance

[image]

`=IF(WEEKDAY(A11)=2,"Monday",IF(WEEKDAY(A11)=3,"Tuesday",IF(WEEKDAY(A11)=4,"Wednesday",IF(WEEKDAY(A11)=5,"Thursday",IF(WEEKDAY(A11)=6,"Friday")*(W11/X11*Y11*1.25)))))`

No error message, the syntaxs is wrong

Comment: You want to get the Value in `Z` if the Day in `A` is not a Weekday ?

Comment: yes, absolutely right

Answer (score 0):

Your formula does not produce a syntax error for me. It returns the day of the week in words and it works exactly as written.

In the IF statements you return the day name as text. The text for Friday is then multiplied by `(W11/X11*Y11*1.25)` . Since text will not be multiplied with numbers, the result is still text.

You probably don't want this. You probably want the calculation to occur only for weekdays, so you could use a formula like this

```
=IF(and(WEEKDAY(A11)>=2,WEEKDAY(A11)<=6),(W11/X11*Y11*1.25),"no calculation")
```

In words: if the number of the weekday is between 2 and 6, do the calculation.

Comment: If this solves your issue, please mark the answer as described in the [tour]